# Dynamatically create StackedColumnSeries by xaml

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I create a stack chart and it has 2 seriesDefinition.
It work fine.

```
<chartingToolkit:Chart>
<chartingToolkit:StackedColumnSeries>
    <chartingToolkit:SeriesDefinition
        DataContext="{Binding Path=CostDetail[0]}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding fees}"
        DependentValuePath="Fee"
        IndependentValuePath="PrjName"
        Title="{Binding title}"/>
    <chartingToolkit:SeriesDefinition
        DataContext="{Binding Path=CostDetail[1]}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding fees}"
        DependentValuePath="Fee"
        IndependentValuePath="PrjName"
        Title="{Binding title}"/>
</chartingToolkit:StackedColumnSeries>
```

Now I want it can create seriesDefinitions Dynamically using data-binding. like this:

```
//-------------DesignData File Begin (CostData.xaml)----------------//
<CostDemo_Model:CostData.CostDetail>
    <CostDemo_Model:StackColumn title="plane">
        <CostDemo_Model:StackColumn.fees>
            <CostDemo_Model:PrjFee2 Fee="11" PrjName="costKind1"/>
            <CostDemo_Model:PrjFee2 Fee="75" PrjName="costKind2"/>
            <CostDemo_Model:PrjFee2 Fee="60" PrjName="costKind3"/>
            <CostDemo_Model:PrjFee2 Fee="30" PrjName="costKind4"/>
            <CostDemo_Model:PrjFee2 Fee="10" PrjName="costKind5"/>
        </CostDemo_Model:StackColumn.fees>
    </CostDemo_Model:StackColumn>
    <CostDemo_Model:StackColumn title="Train">
        <CostDemo_Model:StackColumn.fees>
            <CostDemo_Model:PrjFee2 Fee="41" PrjName="costKind1"/>
            <CostDemo_Model:PrjFee2 Fee="70" PrjName="costKind2"/>
            <CostDemo_Model:PrjFee2 Fee="50" PrjName="costKind3"/>
            <CostDemo_Model:PrjFee2 Fee="51" PrjName="costKind4"/>
            <CostDemo_Model:PrjFee2 Fee="10" PrjName="costKind5"/>
        </CostDemo_Model:StackColumn.fees>
    </CostDemo_Model:StackColumn>
</CostDemo_Model:CostData.CostDetail>

//-------------DesignData File End (CostData.xaml)----------------//

//-------------View File Start(CostAnalysis.xaml)----------------//

<UserControl d:DataContext="{d:DesignData Source=/Model/Design/CostData.xaml}" >
<UserControl.Resources>
    <toolkit:ObjectCollection x:Name="mySeries">
             for(i=0; i<CostDetail.Count; i++){
           <chartingToolkit:SeriesDefinition
            DataContext="{Binding Path=CostDetail[i]}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding fees}"
            DependentValuePath="Fee"
            IndependentValuePath="PrjName"
            Title="{Binding title}"/>
             }
    </toolkit:ObjectCollection>
</UserControl.Resources>

<chartingToolkit:Chart>
    <chartingToolkit:StackedColumnSeries SeriesDefinitions ={StaticResources mySeries}>
    </chartingToolkit:StackedColumnSeries>
</chartingToolkit:Chart>
</UserControl>


//-------------View File End(CostAnalysis.xaml)----------------//
```

But I don't know how.
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

would somethin like this be possible as a Solution:

```
<chartingToolkit:StackedColumnSeries DataContext="{Binding CostDetail}">
  <DataTemplate>
    <chartingToolkit:SeriesDefinition 
        ItemsSource="{Binding fees}" 
        DependentValuePath="Fee" 
        IndependentValuePath="PrjName" 
        Title="{Binding title}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</chartingToolkit:StackedColumnSeries>
```

If you have another solution for this problem in the meantime, I would be interested in it as well :-)

Best Regards,
Andreas

Comment: Andreas, thx for ur reply. I try but it dosn't work. It seems '<DataTemplate>' cannt be put in <chartingToolkit:StackedColumnSerie>.